# WMF & Qt Can not get the signal in slot from OnProcessSample

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, wmf

Now I'm using the WMF to show up the real camera frame on Qt. 
At first it's ok to get the image frame in OnProcessSample that is in my Grabber class inherited from IMFSampleGrabberSinkCallback with WMF regularly.

WMF.CPP

```
STDMETHODIMP Grabber::OnProcessSample
(
REFGUID guidMajorMediaType,
DWORD dwSampleFlags,
LONGLONG llSampleTime,
LONGLONG llSampleDuration,
const BYTE * pSampleBuffer,
DWORD dwSampleSize
)

{

  QMutexLocker locker(&m_SampleMutex);

  pMySignal->setValue();

  return S_OK;
}
```

In order to notify the getting of frame to UI, i tried to create the simple classes inherited from QObject with Signal & Slot like the following.

MainWindow.h

```
class MySignal : public QObject
{
     Q_OBJECT

     public:
      MySignal(QObject * parent = 0, char* name = 0)
      {
           setObjectName ( name );
      }

      void setValue() { emit EnvokeSignal(); }

public slots:
      void ReceiveSignal();

signals:
     void EnvokeSignal();
};

class MySignal2 : public QObject
{
     Q_OBJECT

     public:
      MySignal2(QObject * parent = 0, char* name = 0)
      {
           setObjectName ( name );
      }

      void setValue() { emit EnvokeSignal2(); }

      public slots:
      void ReceiveSignal2();

     signals:
     void EnvokeSignal2();
};
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
MySignal* pMySignal;

void MySignal::ReceiveSignal()
{
    //qDebug()<<"Objectname = "<< objectName() <<" val = "<< v;
    OutputDebugString(L" === ReceiveSignal === \n");
}

void MySignal2::ReceiveSignal2()
{
    //qDebug()<<"Objectname = "<< objectName() <<" val = "<< v;
    OutputDebugString(L" === ReceiveSignal === \n");
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    MySignal SignalSlotCleass(0, "a");
    MySignal2 Signal2SlotCleass(0, "b");


    pMySignal = &SignalSlotCleass;

    QObject::connect( &SignalSlotCleass, &MySignal::EnvokeSignal, &Signal2SlotCleass, &MySignal2::ReceiveSignal2 );

    EnumerateCamDevice_StartupMF();
}
```

When I use only two classes like MySignal1, MySignal2,  I could get the Signal message in Slot method. But If i tried to merge WMF.cpp with OnProcessSample function, I couldn't get the signal message sent from OnProcessSample in Slot function. 
If anyone knows this issue, Could you give me some tips to overcome it?

Answer (score 0):

After the function on_pushButton_clicked() is completed your objects SignalSlotCleass and Signal2SlotCleass are deleted. Because its created on stack. For example you can do it like this:

SignalsHandler.h

```
class SignalsHandler
{
public:
    // if you want you can use any other smart pointer
    // or even simple pointer but don`t forget clear memory
    QSharedPointer<MySignal> pMySignal; 
    QSharedPointer<MySignal2> pMySignal2;
public:
    void SignalsHandler() :
        pMySignal( new MySignal(0, "a") ),
        pMySignal( new MySignal2(0, "b") )
    {
        QObject::connect( pMySignal, &MySignal::EnvokeSignal, pMySignal2, &MySignal2::ReceiveSignal2 );
    }
};
```

WMF.CPP

```
STDMETHODIMP Grabber::OnProcessSample
(
REFGUID guidMajorMediaType,
DWORD dwSampleFlags,
LONGLONG llSampleTime,
LONGLONG llSampleDuration,
const BYTE * pSampleBuffer,
DWORD dwSampleSize
)
{

    QMutexLocker locker(&m_SampleMutex);

    // or you can pass hndl like a parameter of function
    SignalsHandler hndl;
    hndl.pMySignal->setValue();

    return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate with your comment. It's actually helpful~ Thanks ^__^